# how to set var including quotes in a command variable

Tags: python

I have the following cmd,am trying to equate data in var including quotes to changes('changes=var' as shown below),can anyone suggest the syntax to do it?

```
var = "769373 769374"

cmd = ['tool', '--server=commander.company.com', 'runProcedure', 'Android_Main',
       '--procedureName', 'priority_kw', '--actualParameter',
       `'changes=var'`,
       'gerrit_server=review-android.company.com']
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here - can you elaborate?  What happens when you try it now?  What would you like to happen?

Comment: Just use `'changes=' + var`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **+** to concatenate in Python.  Example below show how it's used:

```
cmd = ['tool', '--server=commander.company.com', 'runProcedure', 'Android_Main',
   '--procedureName', 'priority_kw', '--actualParameter',
   'changes=' + var, 'gerrit_server=review-android.company.com']
```

Comment: It should be `'changes=' + var, 'gerrit...'`. You've got an extra `+` in there and you put the `,` inside a string when it should be outside of it, separating items in the list.

Comment: is it? I'm a bit confused by what he/she is trying to do there. I assumed the backticks are surrounding it in hopes that it would make Python interpret the `var` inside `'changes=var'` as a variable instead of a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it this way:

```
var = "769373 769374"
cmd = ['tool', '--server=commander.company.com', 'runProcedure', 'Android_Main',
       '--procedureName', 'priority_kw', '--actualParameter',
       'changes={}'.format(var),
       'gerrit_server=review-android.company.com']
```

Using string concatenation (`'changes=' + var`) works fine in this case, but that approach will sometimes fail when you're not expecting it to. For example, if `var` was an `int`, you'd get a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`.

Comment: @miR Hmm, I still interpret the original post differently. I'll let the OP clarify and edit if necessary.